# asp.net mvc4 default controller on iis8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, iis-8

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 web application originally developed on IIS 7.5. RouteConfig:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

AdminAreaRegistration:

```
context.MapRoute(
    name: "Admin",
    url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "AdminIndex", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
);
```

On IIS 7.5 everything works fine. After deployment to IIS 8 url /Admin/ returns error 403. But it works if controller name is specified: /Admin/AdminIndex/. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a temporary solution updated web.config with:
    <urlMappings enabled="true">
        <add url="~/Admin" mappedUrl="~/Admin/AdminIndex" />
    </urlMappings>
It works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the sequence of the routes.